# why special characters displaying in browser instead of hyphen

Tags: html, encoding

[image]

my html code portion
  please check this

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">

  <h5><label>Yard Maintenance  </label></h5>

  <input id="67" class="css-checkbox" name="yard[]" type="checkbox" value="Initial Grass Cut – Less than 5,000 Square Feet" />
  <label for="67" name="67" class="css-label"> 
    Initial Grass Cut – Less than 5,000 Square Feet </label><br/>
  <input id="68" class="css-checkbox" name="yard[]" type="checkbox" value="Initial Grass Cut – 5,000-9,999 Square Feet" />
  <label for="68" name="68" class="css-label">Initial Grass Cut – 5,000-9,999 Square Feet</label><br/>
  <input id="69" class="css-checkbox" name="yard[]" type="checkbox" value="Initial Grass Cut – 10,000-14,999 Square Feet" />
  <label for="69" name="69" class="css-label">Initial Grass Cut – 10,000-14,999 Square Feet  </label><br/>

  <input id="70" name="yard[]" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Initial Grass Cut – 10,000-14,999 Square Feet" />
  <label for="70" name="70" class="css-label">Initial Grass Cut – 10,000-14,999 Square Feet  </label><br>
  <input id="71" name="yard[]" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Re-Cut – Less than 5,000 Square Feet" />
  <label for="71" name="71" class="css-label">Re-Cut – Less than 5,000 Square Feet </label><br/>

  <input id="72" name="yard[]" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Re-Cut – 5,000-9,999 Square Feet" />
  <label for="72" name="72" class="css-label">Re-Cut – 5,000-9,999 Square Feet  </label><br/>

  <input id="73" name="yard[]" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Re-Cut – 10,000-14,999 Square Feet" />
  <label for="73" name="73" class="css-label">Re-Cut – 10,000-14,999 Square Feet  </label><br/>

  <input id="74" name="yard[]" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Re-Cut – Over 15,000 Square Feet" />
  <label for="74" name="74" class="css-label">Re-Cut – Over 15,000 Square Feet </label><br/>

  <input id="75" name="yard[]" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Snow Removal" />
  <label for="75" name="75" class="css-label">Snow Removal </label> <br/>

  <input id="76" name="yard[]" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Tree or Shrub Trimming" />
  <label for="76" name="76" class="css-label">Tree or Shrub Trimming   </label><br>
  <input id="77" name="yard[]" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Dead Tree Removal" />
  <label for="77" name="77" class="css-label">Dead Tree Removal  </label><br/>

  <input id="78" name="yard[]" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Weed Removal" />
  <label for="78" name="78" class="css-label">Weed Removal </label><br/>

</div>
```

in browser my labels are displaying with special characters.please help me to get out of this issue i tried encoding also.its still not working

Comment: It shows correctly for me in fiddle. What encoding are you using? Also I put your hyphen and a hyphen I typed into a unicode converter and got different hex results (yours: 2013, mine: 002D)

Answer (score 0):

This is an encoding issue.

The best solution is to save and display your pages using `Unicode` encoding.

At the very top of your document, have the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>[... YOUR PAGE TITLE...]</title>
```

Also, ensure that you save your `html` file as `utf-8`.

Comment: still same issue

Comment: my file is php file

Comment: Your generated `html` document begins twice. You have two `doctypes`, two `<html>` elements, two `<head>` elements and so on.

Comment: Your hyphen is actually U+2013 En dash, either make it a regular dash or you have to use an encoding that will properly recognize it. The symbol your seeing is the generic "I have no clue what this is" translation.